# Different versions of Crystal Reports runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I have two WinForm applications that use CR runtime to generate reprts.When CR runtime 13.20 is installed, the newer application will complain that it can't find and load CR 13.21 (13.0.350) assembly. If I upgrade CR runtime to 13.21 (13.0.350) that new application will work but the older one errors out with exception stating that it can't find and load CR runtime assembly 13.20 (13.0.200).
All workstations operate on CR runtime 13.20 so how can I make new app created in VS2015 with CR 13.21 environment operate correctly on older CR runtime?

Comment: Check the versions on your references to CrystalObjects in both projects.  I suspect each project is referencing a different version.  If this is the case, then updating the references in both projects to use the same version should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, remove CR Runtime reference from your old application and add a reference to CR 13.21 it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  The client machines have apps that use 13.0.20 and mine that uses 13.0.21.  I do have my reference set for 13.0.21.  But the problem we encountered was the SAP installer fro 13.0.21 forced us to remove 13.0.20 from the client workstation.  Thus, all the other apps threw assembly not found errors.

Is there a way to install 20 and 21 at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your engine to match the latest version that you have. For example in my case. my engine was running on 13.2 and the newest .dll files that i've got were 13.5, therefore using Nuget console you can directly upgrade the engine from visual studio (example Install-Package CrystalReports.Engine -Version 13.0.3500)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell your "old crystal runtime app" to use the new crystal reports runtime. All you have to do is to create AssemblyBindings in your app.config file:

```
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3500.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          [...]
    </assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a config file to redirect the old application to use the newer runtime. 
Use Notepad to create a file name **your_old_app_exe_name.exe.config** in the folder where your old app (the one that uses the older Crystal runtime) lives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>    
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Web" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>    
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Prompting" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>  
</runtime>
</configuration>
```