# CR13 SP27 Runtime not support ​CR13 SP21?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working on VS2019 and CR13 SP27. I installed my program on another computer and installed CR27 runtime. When I run my new program all is good and reports show without error.

But when I want to run my another program that I ever installed (my old program working on VS2017 and CR13 SP21 and installed CR21 runtime in client computer), it gives an error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified.

I wonder if CR13 SP27 Runtime does not support CR13 SP21 runtime?

Before I install SP27 runtime I uninstalled SP21 runtime. Is it related?

How to make all my programs work well with CR report difference version on another computer?

Comment: Most likely this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927365/different-versions-of-crystal-reports-runtime

Comment: This due to different versions of runtime in client pc against your report using dlls. Your report is compiled with SP27 and the client pc gives the reference of SP21 so the error occurs. The above link by @MatSnow is a good example to try changing dlls or I suggest to stick with one version or change the runtime version in client pc every time you upgrade your version. I am using VS2017 with SP24 and not upgraded. Versions don't have any upgrade except support and bug fixes for VS2019 I guess.